# Как превратить данные значения в код?

Tags: html, css

Привет есть в фотошопе такая тень
как это выглядит в коде?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по скрину, в вашей версии Photoshop, есть возможность получения CSS. Правый клик на слое > "Копировать CSS". У меня получился следующий результат: `box-shadow: 0px 0px 4.75px 0.25px rgba(0, 0, 2, 0.27);`

Comment: Также вы можете применять этот генератор создания теней https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow